# Install ssl certificate Nginx port 443 refuse connection

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have installed my certificate and configured my nginx to listen to port 443. But still cannot connect to port 443. Missing something??

In my ssl.conf

## HTTPS server configuration

#

```
server {
listen   443 ssl;
server_name  www.newbullets.co.nz newbullets.co.nz;

ssl                  on;
ssl_certificate  /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-bundle.crt;
ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/server.key;

ssl_session_timeout  5m;


#location / {
#    root   html;
#    index  index.html index.htm;
#}
```

}

and default.config

```
server {
listen   80;
server_name  newbullets.co.nz www.newbullets.co.nz;
#charset koi8-r;
#access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

location / {
 auth_basic "input you user name and password";
 auth_basic_user_file /var/www/www.newbullets.co.nz/.htpasswd;
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html/nb/;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
}
```

Update

I added following to my ssl.conf, now in Firefox it displays the webpage but SSL green bar is gone, and Chrome still downloads the webpage. any idea?

```
 location ~ \.php$ {
    root           html;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /usr/share/nginx/html/nb$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Check your firewall and make sure port 443 is open.  Often default firewall configurations  don't open up 443 along with 80.
2. Ensure the ssl.conf is called with an include from somewhere.  I've beaten my head against a non-functioning config that seemed right only to discover it wasn't being included and loaded at all.
3. Change the "listen" directive to: `listen 443 default_server ssl;`

Comment: Its working now but one problem is when I point to the https url it downloaded the index.php file instead of display the webpage, in my ssl.conf location directive I have{index  index.html index.htm index.php;root   /usr/share/nginx/html/nb/;} any idea?

Comment: Do you have php-fpm installed and configured?  I don't see a fastcgi_index pointing at a php-fpm backend. This might help: http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/installing-nginx-and-php-fpm-setup-for-nginx

Comment: Hi there, please see my update I added php location directive into my config and firefox now displays the webpage but the browser ssl green bar is gone, and Chrome still downloaded the webpage

Comment: That's odd.  Can you post the HTTP headers received when you load the page?  I bet the content-type is set wrong.

Comment: This is fixed after reboot my VPS and restarting my server

Comment: Could you please gime me more details or a link which explains how to make sure port 443 os open and about the ssl.conf?

Comment: Make sure if you use docker, open the port.

Answer (score 2):

my solution:

**in brief**: in `CentOS 7`, use firewall tool `firewalld` or `iptables` to **MAKESURE** `https 443` port be open.

**in detail**:

as `@Greg Lund-Chaix` says, you should make sure 443 port open.

my here is, even if `netstat` show listen 443 port:

```
[root@crifan.com nginx]# netstat -nlp | grep nginx    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2193/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2193/nginx: master
```

while `Aliyun ECS`'s `Security Group` has add rule to `allow in for 443 port`,

but actually here `iptables -L` output can NOT see `https`:

```
iptables -L --line-numbers
...
Chain IN_public_allow (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh ctstate NEW
2    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ftp-data ctstate NEW
3    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ftp ctstate NEW
4    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh ctstate NEW
5    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http ctstate NEW
6    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ddi-tcp-1 ctstate NEW
7    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpts:39000:safetynetp ctstate NEW
```

and finnaly use `firewalld` to add the `https` and `443` port:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-service=https --permanent
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=443/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

or use `iptables` to insert before http(num=5) :

`iptables -I IN_public_allow 5 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT`

then not forget to save changes:

`service iptables save`